# SQL case when FROM(UNIX_TIME)

Tags: mysql

I am writing simple sql select but the problem raised up. When I run following select

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN t.escalation_time =0 THEN 987
          ELSE 789
      END
FROM ticket t WHERE t.id =1
```

everything is fine. But when run these few lines, output is mismatched (it gives "random" numbers).

```
  SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN t.escalation_time = 0 THEN 0
          ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME( t.escalation_time )
      END
FROM ticket t WHERE t.id =1
```

I am wondering it could be problem with the function called FROM_UNIXTIME. But on the other hand, as a standalone function it works perfectly. The awaiting result is to show 0 (in case 0) instead of 1970-01-01 01:00:00.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add samples of data and mismatched results?

Comment: Yep, result of the select mentioned above is one row with value 30.

Comment: He meant to put a small dump of your table here, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked the first thing (data samples :) ). In fact it is quite big table...But I have extracted something. [link](http://pastebin.com/9tnriN5U)

Comment: That's not enough data to reproduce the problem. There's just one row where the escalation_time is 0. How do you expect us to test the `ELSE` part in your `CASE WHEN`? Also you should read up about indexing strategies. An index on every column is definitely not the way to go. Also you got multiple indexes on the same column. Insert some more rows here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5814ac/3/0

Comment: Thanks, I will study something more about indexes. Schema is ready right now. I have tried to run the select and it  gives right values. I am so confused about it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) returns a timestamp value. From the [manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html).

> TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

What can be confusing now, is the fact that timezones are considered with timestamp.

If you're in the timezone GMT+1h, this

```
select unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00');
```

returns

```
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Since timezone is considered, this

```
select unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 01:00:00');
```

still returns

```
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 01:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

But this...

```
select unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 01:00:01');
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 01:00:01') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

and this

```
select unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 02:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('1970-01-01 02:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                  3600 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

now return "correct" values.

UPDATE:

Easy and quick solution:

```
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN t.escalation_time = 0 THEN 0
          WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME( t.escalation_time ) = '1970-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 0
          ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME( t.escalation_time )
      END
FROM ticket t WHERE t.id =1
```

Comment: Thanks, that was first part that i could not handle. But another thing drives me mad. I would like to have just '0' (nothing more) value instead of the full date ('1970-01-01 01:00:00').

Comment: Even my select works at schema (sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5814ac/3/0). But when  I run this select on my own db, it returns '323031342d30332d31322031343a32383a3034' instead of '2014-03-12 13:28:04' considering the last insert with id = 128.

Comment: ? Your fiddle isn't different from mine. And with 128 I get proper values. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0480/2/0 Make it reproducable or else we can't help.

Comment: I have added this line [link](http://pastebin.com/pPcsYjA9). I was working with your fiddle so I thought it replicated this line to u too. Fiddle works great, my own db returns mismatched results.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/788da/1/0 Seems to be in your code...

Comment: It seems like an error of our version sql. Everything works fine on various others servers. Even when select is not in condition statement works fine. Conclusion: We have to upgrade sql server. I can't thanks enough.