# MYSQL: Bug using FROM_UNIXTIME(0) with CASE in older version?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to format my date with CASE statement in MySQL client version: 5.1.41. reviewed_on int(11) default 0 is designed to store epoch/unix timestamp. Instead of getting 0 or dd/mm/yyyy, the result prepend 3 with true result i.e if true result is 0 then it returns 30; if it's 10 then it returns 3130...

I checked various links along with the one [SQL case when FROM(UNIX_TIME)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346840/sql-case-when-fromunix-time)

**Conclusion from @Martin Orem is to upgrade sql version**. Is it the only solution or we can still fix this and get the desired output? Any help will be appreciated.

```
mysql>SELECT reviewed_on AS reviewed_on FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 0                    |
+----------------------+

mysql>SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(reviewed_on) AS reviewed_on FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 1970-01-01 01:00:00  |
+----------------------+

mysql>SELECT CASE reviewed_on WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS reviewed_on
FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 0                    |
+----------------------+

mysql>SELECT CASE reviewed_on WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(reviewed_on, '%d/%m/%Y') END AS reviewed_on
FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 30                   |
+----------------------+

mysql>SELECT CASE reviewed_on WHEN 0 THEN 10 ELSE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(reviewed_on), '%d/%m/%Y') END AS reviewed_on
FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 3130                 |
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered this question. I did some work-around and changed the column `reviewed_on` to `type date DEFAULT NULL`. It works.

```
mysql>SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(reviewed_on, '%d/%m/%Y'), '0') AS reviewed_on FROM table_name
+----------------------+
| reviewed_on          |
+----------------------+
| 27/03/2018           |
+----------------------+
| 0                    |
+----------------------+
```